# Strange translation in django

Tags: python, django, templates, translation, po

I have a template in which I have placed a tag:

```
{% trans 'Products'%}
```

In English, everything is ok - I have the "Products".
When I switch on the Polish language page
I have: "Produkty" and I would like to have "Products".
However, in the .po files - I do not have the settings on the Polish and English of the word.

Comment: Maybe it is using the translation from Django translation files?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão No, in my django translation files there is no such word.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão The reason may be that I did not use: django-admin.py compilemessages ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe default translations of Django contains this word? Just add, within your local .po file:

```
msgid "Products"
msgstr ""
```